# erlang from windows command line

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Anyone knows how to open the Erlang shell from windows command line?
In official tutorial recommended to write "werl" to the command prompt but this command doesn't work.
P.S. I have installed erlang to my PC.

Comment: add path to erlang bin into environment variable PATH.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Please be specific and publish the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 simple ways to start an erlang shell on windows.

1) you can open a terminal directly into the folder that contains werl.exe you want. Use Shift + right click and choose "open terminal here". Then type "werl.exe"

2) you can go into that folder using "cd path", then type "werl.exe"

Also if you use werl.exe, a new window will open. If you want to stay with your windows terminal you should use erl.exe

Comment: Well at the moment it's hard to answer this question as the OP hasn't really even posted the error message...

Answer (score 0):

werl uses the wxwidget library. Everything is installed automatically if you use the [windows binary file](http://erlang.org/download/otp_win64_19.3.exehttp://).

If you have installed from source, then wxwidget must be installed separately.

It is possible to start the erlang shell in a dos window: start a command window with cmd, and start the erlang shell from this window using erl.

I guess that you already checked that werl exe is in the search path.